# mongoose node.js how to insert location coordinates into array [ ] without double quotes or single quotes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation

I need to save location coordinates in to array. but it storing within double quotes. I am using mongoose node.js
Actually I need like this

```
"user_geo" : [
    8.725535976399259,
    8.725535976399259
    ]
```

but my data is getting saved like this

```
"user_geo" : [
    "8.725535976399259,
    8.725535976399259"
    ]
```

That is, its getting saved with double quotes. My mongoose schema is

```
var venue_schema = new mongoose.Schema({ venue_name:String, user_geo:[]});
```

please could any one help to solve this issue. Thanks advance...

Comment: That's not syntactically correct for a js array, where are you getting that output?

Comment: i am reading data from json file.... it has like this..  geo:{lat="12.889822", lng="20.887632"}

Answer (score 0):

As you need only a pair of coordinates, create Mongoose schema as

```
var venue_schema = new mongoose.Schema({ venue_name: String, 
                                         user_geo_lat: Number, 
                                         user_geo_long: Number })
```

or do

```
var venue_schema = new mongoose.Schema({ venue_name: String, 
                                         user_geo: [Number]);
```

if you really want an array.

Comment: no its not wolking....in json I am having data like this
geo:{lat="12.889822",
lng="20.887632"}

Comment: @imran which suggestion doesn't work?  have you tested both?

Comment: No I tested with the second one... Let me check with the first one and get back to you...